# wget: Edit broken links while crawling before visiting them

Tags: wget

Situation:
I want to mirror an old website. This website is on `https://example.com/website/`. The website uses absolute links to `http://www.example.com/website/`.

Problem:
For whatever reason, wget cannot reach `https://www.example.com` (the www. folder), the connection will just timeout - no idea why, it works fine in the browser (neither can curl btw).

Possible solutions:

- Have wget rewrite the links before following them while it's still crawling.
- Make wget work with the www. folder.

To maybe make .www work, I already tried setting the user-agent to FF: `--header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0"` but that did not work.

So I somehow need to rewrite the links on that website while crawling.

Comment: Not possible with pure wget. Find out why it times out.

Comment: So are the links to `https:` or `http:` URLs.. you are talking about both.

Comment: I have no idea how I could find out why www. does not work. wget/curl debug give no hint.  The links are to http: but that does not really matter since HSTS enforces https:. The server works fine with https, also on the www. folder. If I run the same wget command from my home PC it downloads everything as expected (in my question I run wget from my server - but it's also not an IP block, because the non-www. stuff works (I usually crawl `https://example.com/site/` without issues)).